# dot net programing udp buffersize error

Tags: .net, sockets, udp, protocol-buffers

I am trying to send an image (byte[]) over a UDP broadcast socket. I
get the following error stating that my message is bigger than the
internal message buffer.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
occurred in System.dll

Additional information: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger
than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the
buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram
itself

From looking around google, I am under the impression that this is a
general winsock error and not something directly related to the .net
implementation. I thought that if a message was bigger than the
internal buffer, winsock would break up the message and on UDP,
guarantee order, but not delivery. Is this different for a broadcast
socket? Do I need to handle breaking apart the message myself?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I doubt it will guarantee order.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol):

> The field size sets a theoretical limit of 65,535 bytes

Which means that you cannot send images larger that 65,535 bytes (probably a bit less than that)

I would avoid UDP if I could when sending images, since it do not guarantee delivery or message order.